# Postgresql foreign key in replication

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, replication

Sorry I'm new to Postgresql (switched from MySQL due to its horrible performance) so I have a question regarding PSQL replication. Does foreign keys work in Postgresql with replication?

My guess is that syncing across multiple instances definitely has overhead and if a foreign key has to be checked before insertion, there'll be a performance penalty. Therefore, I don't know whether foreign keys work but slow or just don't work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different modes of replication, but foreign keys work regardless of whether you are using it or not.

A foreign key only references data within the same database however, not across servers. You might want to look at Greenplum's commercial offering if you need that sort of thing.

You *will* need to decide which type of replication suits your requirements though - the built-in (since 9.0) WAL-based streaming replication, or something trigger-based like Slony or Bucardo. There is also pgpool which in addition to being a connection pooler can copy statements to multiple servers.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling